# WLP :: Change default context root on http

Tags: websphere, websphere-liberty

When I do a http get on my websphere liberty profile v8.5.5 (let's assume http://my.domain.com) I'm presented with a nice page that says amongs other things
"Welcome to the WebSphere Application Server V8.5 Liberty Profile"

It looks like this http://rdt1.demos.ibm.com/

How do I configure my server to not display this page and perhaps redirect my request to a login page on https?

Is this a configuration related to a new context root of a new app to be installed? Like this answer below?
[How to make "HTTPS redirect" work on WebSphere Application Server Liberty Profile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17448365/how-to-make-htts-redirect-work-on-websphere-application-server-liberty-profile)
I feel like this should be something configured on server.xml but I can't find any reference to this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can turn that page off by adding the following to your server.xml file:

```
<httpDispatcher enableWelcomePage="false" />
```

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/api/content/nl/en-us/SSRTLW_9.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.multiplatform.doc/autodita/rwlp_metatype_4ic.html#mtFile119

**edit:**

I should clarify, the other answer is also correct. If you install an application with "/" as the context root, it will be used instead of the main page.

If you add something like the following to that application's web.xml:

```
<security-constraint>
    <display-name>Some constraint</display-name>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>All</web-resource-name>
        <description>All URLs</description>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <description>All users</description>
        <role-name>User</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
    <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

You will get the https redirect that you're asking for.

**Additional edit (per comment)**, the following is a more complete example of how to set up the redirect: 
[How to make "HTTPS redirect" work on WebSphere Application Server Liberty Profile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17448365/how-to-make-htts-redirect-work-on-websphere-application-server-liberty-profile)

Comment: Good info about `enableWelcomePage`, thx. However it will only display 404 instead of welcome page, nor will redirect to anything else. So if @Silva wants to have his app displayed on the `/`, he will need to map his application to it. And adding this piece to web.xml is not enough alone, as you will need to configure ssl on Liberty also.

Comment: you're right, I added a link to another SO question that gives a more complete picture for https redirect.

Answer (score 4):

Just create your application and in the `server.xml` specify context root as follows:

```
<webApplication id="MyApp" location="MyApp.war" name="MyApp" contextRoot="/"/>
```

If you want to redirect to login page and ssl, then you will need to do all steps in the post you quoted and of course provide login page in your application.

If you want just to disable the welcome page, add to `server.xml` fragment provided by [ebullient](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26874378/3701228) or even extend it by adding some javascript code which would make the redirect:

```
<httpDispatcher enableWelcomePage="false" appOrContextRootMissingMessage='&lt;script&gt;document.location.href="/MyApp/";&lt;/script&gt;'></httpDispatcher>
```