# How to intercept a url and redirect it to a jsp page?

Tags: java, jsp

I want to develop a `application` and `deploy` in `WebSphere` where the requirement is:

if there are any request like `http://appserver1:9080/` -  it will reach to a landing jsp page

```
for example http://appserver1:9080/index.jsp
```

> Is it at all possible to redirect to a page even if I don't mention
>   the resource name?

Comment: you can use response.sendRedirect() method to redirect to a jsp

Comment: Your second question : yes you can. But i am not sure with .jsp it works with .html'

Comment: This can also be handled while deploying the application as EAR in Websphere. While deploying put the context root as '/' and the functionality I wanted will work. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to redirect from server's root, this is not about your java code or project configuration, it is about server configuration.
Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26874378/517134) for WebSphere configuration.

For JEE projects, on web.xml, you can define as;

```
<web-app>  
 ....  

  <welcome-file-list>  
   <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>  
   <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>  
  </welcome-file-list>  
</web-app>
```

So

http://localhost:8080/myproject

will load index.jsp

[Source](http://www.javatpoint.com/welcome-file-list) for details

Comment: Thanks for the response. The above is working fine.
But the requirement actually is this,

I will just invoke the URL: http://localhost:8080/ 
and this will redirect me to my landing page for example home.jsp.
I want to know whether it is possible if I don't mention the /myproject name in the URL.

Comment: @paularka90 Ok this is not about your java code or project code. this is about your server configuration. For websphere, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/26874378/517134 it may help.

Answer (score 1):

From what you are describing, the redirection can be pretty much handled by servlets mapping. Read here:

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs92/webapp/configureservlet.html

You can be able to intercept URL requests and process:

// Servlet definition on your web.xml

```
<servlet>
<servlet-name>ServletHandler</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>com.servlets.ServletHandler</servlet-class>
</servlet>
```

// This maps all requests to the above defined servlet for processing:

```
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>ServletHandler</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You can define welcome files in web.xml

```
<web-app>
    ...
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp/welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    ...
</web-app>
```

But according to the spec index.html, index.htm and index.jsp are welcome files by default. So you probably don't need to configure anything when the file is called index.jsp.