# Modify Default context root in Websphere Liberty Error CWWKZ0013E

Tags: webserver, websphere-liberty

I am trying to run my application without having a default context root, i.e. I want `localhost:8080` to redirect to my homepage rather than go to `localhost:8080/myapp`

For this in `server.xml` I put the following lines:

```
<httpDispatcher enableWelcomePage="false" />
<webApplication id="MYAPP" name="MYAPP" contextRoot="/" location="dropins/MYAPP.war" />
```

I get an error

```
[ERROR   ] CWWKZ0013E: It is not possible to start two applications called MYAPP.
```

However if I put in the dropins folder `myapp.war` instead of `MYAPP.war` this error doesn't come and the app works. However in the apps/expanded directory I see both `myapp.war` & `MYAPP.war` expanded (even though `MYAPP.war` doesn't exist).

I followed the instructions in [WLP :: Change default context root on http](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26873827/wlp-change-default-context-root-on-http). Could some guide me where I might be going wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't use `<webApplication>` with `dropins/`.  Instead, move the WAR to the `apps/` directory and use `<webApplication ... location="MYAPP.war"/>`.