# how to generate new SSL certificate in websphere application server liberty v. 8.5.5.0

Tags: ssl, https, websphere, websphere-liberty

I am just looking for some information. 
I want to enable ssl and https redirect on (some basic security so I can expose the appCenter and apps for testing):

```
Websphere application server liberty v. 8.5.5.0 
windows server 2008 R2
Java version 1.7.0_71 64bit
```

What I did: 
Installed eclipse + mobilefirst studio
then websphere application server liberty v. 8.5.5.0
then the MobileFirst Platform Server

I read the guide [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSD28V_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.core.doc/ae/twlp_sec_ssl.html) and the security utility [guide](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSD28V_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.core.doc/ae/twlp_sec_create_certificate.html?lang=en)

These guides are quite limited and I am very new to WebSphere, I have questions about how to remove the existing certificate and generate new self-signed on succesfully

I would just like to see a more complete example, some of the related [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17448365/how-to-make-htts-redirect-work-on-websphere-application-server-liberty-profile) here refer to configuring the web.xml but it's not in the documentation.

Can anyone point me to a fuller example that shows how enabling ssl and https redirect are setup?
My end goal is that accessing the appCenter uses ssl and https redirect.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'll try to answer your question in parts, as it is quite broad.

### Enabling SSL

To enable ssl in the Liberty profile the easiest is to use WDT (WebSphere Developer Tools) in Eclipse. in the `Servers` view right click the server and select `Utilities > Create SSL Certificate`. It will:

- Generate Selfsign certificate - you can customize validity period and Subject Name
- Store it in `${server.output.dir}/resources/security/key.jks`
- In the `Console` view it will output piece of code you need to add to your `server.xml`:

> ```
> <featureManager>
>    <feature>ssl-1.0</feature>
> </featureManager>
> <keyStore id="defaultKeyStore" password="{xor}encodedPassword=" />
> ```

You can do the same from command line from `wlp\bin` invoking [securityUtility](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSD28V_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.core.doc/ae/rwlp_command_securityutil.html?lang=en) command:

```
securityUtility createSSLCertificate --server=myserver --password=mypassword --validity=365
                                     --subject=CN=mycompany,O=myOrg,C=myCountry
```

After modifying `server.xml` your Liberty is enabled for SSL on 9443:

`https://localhost:9443/`

### Customizing SSL certificate

Unfortunately there is not much in Liberty itself for it. So here are your options:

- Use `securityUtility` as above - allows to override period and SN
- Use [keytool](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/keytool.html) that comes with JDK, it will allow more customization (name, key length and algorithm), for example:

> ```
> C:\Java\jdk1.7.0_67\bin>keytool -genkeypair -alias myCert -keystore keystore.jks
> Enter keystore password:
> Re-enter new password:
> What is your first and last name?
>   [Unknown]:  liberty
> What is the name of your organizational unit?
>   [Unknown]:  test
> What is the name of your organization?
>   [Unknown]:  gas
> What is the name of your City or Locality?
>   [Unknown]:
> What is the name of your State or Province?
>   [Unknown]:
> What is the two-letter country code for this unit?
>   [Unknown]:
> Is CN=liberty, OU=test, O=gas, L=Unknown, ST=Unknown, C=Unknown correct?
>   [no]:  yes
>
> Enter key password for <mykey>
>         (RETURN if same as keystore password):
> Re-enter new password:
> ```

- Third party tools, for example if you have full WAS you can use [ikeyman](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.ihs.doc/ihs/tihs_certselfsigned.html?cp=SSEQTP_8.5.5&lang=en) to generate certificate using wizard.

Whatever method you will use to create new keystore and self sing cert, update `keyStore` definition in `server.xml`

### Redirection to SSL

By default any unconfigured application will be available over http and https.
If you want to force application to use SSL you will need to create/modify `web.xml` file **for that application**. Add the following to your `web.xml`:

```
<security-constraint>
    <display-name>allApp</display-name>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>allresources</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

And you have to enable application security adding following to `server.xml`:

> ```
> <featureManager>
>     <feature>appSecurity-2.0</feature>
> </featureManager>
> ```

You're done. You have SSL enabled for your server and redirection for given app.

Comment: Many thanks Gas this clarifies things for me quite a bit, I will try this, apologies this might be in the documentation somewhere but where is the web.xml file rather which one? I am marking your response as the answer as I expect it should work I do it right. Thanks again

Comment: @AnthonyK `web.xml` is deployment descriptor for your web application. If you have your application as `.war` file, it will be in the war in the WEB-INF folder, you will need to modify it. If your application is an `.ear`, then you have to look for the `.war` in it. So you have to check either dropins folder or apps in your Liberty server.

Comment: Hi so managed to get the appcenter to listen on 9443 and I can login but when I do i get this error it seems the cert is expired, but I just created the cert using security utility how come its already expired? com.ibm.ws.channel.ssl.internal.SSLHandshakeErrorTracker     E CWWKO0801E: Unable to initialize SSL connection. Unauthorized access was denied or security settings have expired. Exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown

Comment: @AnthonyK If you can access via 9443, check certificate in the browser. The `SSLHandshakeErrorTracker` suggests problem with the establishing SSL connection with some other server. I don't know the MobileFirst platform. If your Liberty server is connecting to other server via SSL it requires that server cert as trusted certificate in the keystore. You need to provide some more info about your setup.